# Extract IP address from ipconfig using Regex

Tags: regex, string

I would like to extract the IPv4 address only from the output below, after running ipconfig, using Regex.

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.local
    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::49b6:17f6:f059:1c3d%12
    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.180
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.254
```

Therefore I would like to extract the '192.168.2.180' address only.

Comment: If you're in an environment where you can run regular expressions, chances are that there's a more direct way to obtain this information (probably in a neater/more "ready for whatever the next step of this process is" form) than by running the `ipconfig` command.

Comment: i connect remotely to a machine, via telnet and automatically run the IPCONFIG command.
All i need is to extract the ip address.

Comment: By the time that the telnet command has connected to the remote machine, it's already had to *find out the IP address*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^ *IPv4 Address[.\s]*:\s*([\d.]+)\s*$`

It does not do any sanity checks on the IP address.

Comment: @Pharaon can you assist with a Regex that gives me just the IP address, without the string of "IPv4 Address" ?

Comment: The regex pattern already groups the IP address. Check group #1 for its contents.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to parse IP addresses, but this one is simple and grabs only what you need:

http://rubular.com/r/PxEX4Lk56w

`\s+IPv4 Address.*: ([\d\.]+)`

Comment: can you assist with a Regex that gives me just the IP address, without the string of "IPv4 Address" ?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to parse a different string now? This and Pharoah's regex will both capture the IP address to a group, which is what you want.

Comment: using Pharoah's i get :
"IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.180"

all i actually need is the address itself "192.168.2.180

Comment: ...no. What language are you using? You need to use *capture groups* to find the IP address alone. For example, in python this would be: `re.match(string, regex).group(1)`.